# UI framework suitable for microservice based architecture

Tags: angular, design-patterns, frontend, web-frameworks, web-frontend

We are building the application which will be used by may customers, we are using kubernatis and docker for hosting and Java for backend we a have to create microservice based architecture.

For UI framework we have Angular and Vue as an option.

My question is we need to use one hosted frontend framework customized UI by customer requirement. How to achieve that? Can we use the same hosted code and do the customization in UI or we have to host customized fronted for every customer??

Comment: Can you describe your question a bit more?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Added Please check.

Comment: When you say customized UI by customer, you refer to visual or functional requirements?

Comment: if you're going to have custom markup for each customer, would a SPA framework really make sense? Why not use Razor views or the like?

Comment: @CarlosOsiel I wish to know for both Visual and functional requirements .